# how to make tabs height fixed in native-base

Tags: react-native, native-base

[image: main view is made of 2 tabs under a view with header body and footer]
all tabs height increase when one tab is list and scrolls in native-base

[image: first tab is ordinary view with some text and second tab is a list of customized card item as follows]

This is how it works

[image: this is how it works]

Comment: try adding props prerenderingSiblingsNumber={1} to Tabs. `<Tabs  prerenderingSiblingsNumber={1}><Tab><TabOne></Tab><Tab><TabTwo></Tab></Tabs>`

Comment: @Mahmood Bkh where u able to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

When you use native-base, try to put `<Tabs />` outside `<Content />` because makes it scrollable.

As in the docs it outside content
https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#tabs-def-headref